# Copy data from an excel and copy automaticly into one Web Form

Tags: forms, web

I have to register 100user manually into an external website. There is any way to copy the information, and when I paste into the web form, parse automatically into the form?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

1. Do one manual registration and then capture that HTTP Request. Use it as a template
2. Export data from excel to csv. (just to make it easier to work on)
3. Loop over each line of csv and create HTTP likely to be POST Request.
4. Check for errors